# It's this a good way in doing getStaticProps with pagination in NextJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I start learning NextJS and I have started working on a project with Formula 1 data.

I was wondering if the way that I am fetching data, using pagination, it's done in proper way.
I am using NextJS 13.

```
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const drivers = [];
  let offset = 0;
  let count = 0;

  // Make API requests until all drivers are fetched
  while (count === 0 || offset < count) {
    const res = await fetch(
      `http://ergast.com/api/f1/drivers.json?limit=50&offset=${offset}`
    );
    const json = await res.json();
    drivers.push(...json.MRData.DriverTable.Drivers);
    offset += 50;
    count = json.MRData.total;
  }

  return {
    props: {
      drivers,
    },
  };
};

export default function Drivers({ drivers }) {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const startIndex = (page - 1) * 50;
  const endIndex = startIndex + 50;
  const displayedDrivers = drivers.slice(startIndex, endIndex);

  const handleNextPage = () => {
    setPage(page + 1);
  };

  const handlePreviousPage = () => {
    setPage(page - 1);
  };
```